# rooting Sony Xperia z3+

Tags: rooting, root-access, sony-xperia-z3

I have this [device](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_z3+-6878.php).  I couln't find any solution of rooting this device and installing xposed framework onto it. Can someone please a link to some working guide(xda maybe) on how to root this device?

Comment: Care to do a bit more research? Xperia phones are easily rootable by unlocking the bootloader first, then flashing a kernel with custom recovery, then flashing SuperSU within it. Dig [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z4) for stuff.

Comment: I did searched. There's this thread http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z5/development/root-automatic-repack-stock-kernel-dm-t3301605

But not sure if these works

Comment: I am afraid if it gets my device bricked

Comment: That's for Z5; although some steps mentioned are indeed useful, you'd better stick to something made for your device specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you download KingoRoot from the Google Play Store or App Store it should automatically root your device. For more help see here:
https://www.kingoapp.com
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-easily-root-an-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

If you would have searched thoroughly then there's this link - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hZDNpp--E0Y
, which would help you in rooting your device.
Also I would like to suggest you to mention the model no., android version, and the build no. of your device before asking for help, which makes helping or suggesting things easier.
And as you said about risk of getting the device bricked, well it could happen even when you follow a tutorial which helped someone but in your case couldn't. You can run into problems during several things like flashing custom ROM, changing kernel, and so on. So its your call on whether you want to get the best out of your device and root your phone or else use it the way it is.